# Simplification in sympy

Tags: sympy

I am new to `sympy`, and I cannot understand why the result of the following piece of code does not results in `f(x)=0`

```
from sympy import *
f = Function('f')
x = Symbol('x')
simplify(Eq(f(x)+1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

When SymPy rewrites `x + x` as `2*x` that is automatic rewriting. Not everything is automatic, however, as you have seen. If you want to know what value of `f(x)` makes that Equality true, you can solve for it:

```
>>> solve(Eq(f(x) + 1, 1), f(x))
[0]
```

Comment: ok, but why if instead of `f(x)` I put a symbol `y` it rewrites as `y = 0`, is something related to functions?

Comment: and what if the expression is more complicate, for example `Eq(f(x)+g(y)+1,h(x,y)+1)`? I could solve with respect to `f(x)`, but it is arbitrary, why not `g(y)` or `h(x,y)`?

Comment: You can solve for whichever of those function you want to have on the lhs of the Eq. You reconstruct the Eq from the result, e.g. `Eq(want, solve(orig, want)[0])` where `want` might be `g(y)` and `orig`, `Eq(f(x)+g(y)+1,h(x,y)+1)`. This will only work if the expression is linear in `want` and `want` is not multiplied by something that can be zero.